# IBM Worklight 6.1 Startup issue after direct update

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst

I have an issue with Worklight 6.1. i have installed two fix packs for the worklight server.

When I install the android app **for the first time** and there is an update available from the server, after the update finishes it shows a white page and not the index.html. if i kill the running app and reopen it  it shows the index page correctly because there is no another update to receive. Is there a starup issue with worklight 6.1 ?

**Edit:**

Also with the direct update option enabled  during the first launch of the app, when the user hit update button the download progress doesn't show and the user doesnt get the update. he gets the update after he kills the app and reopens it from the icon.

Comment: 1) Always provide logs. LogCat and Server. 2) You mention server fixpacks, what about the studio? did you update it as well? 3) What is the studio build number. What is the server build number?

Comment: the android studio version is 6.1.0.01-20140922-2007 the server build number is 6.1.0.02 and as i told it was not nessesary to install another update to the worklight studio when the second fix pack where installed to the server.. there are no relatede errors printed for this issue  to logs or logcat

Comment: I disagree, as Direct Update is made of both server-side code and client-side code and there have been Direct Update fixes, so maybe you are missing some?. Please update Worklight Studio to match the same version as the server component and see if you are getting the same. Please also confirm this behavior with a new application (change the background color of the index.html file to have clearer results).

Comment: @IdanAdar i have set the update silently option to true and the redirection now to index.html is working.. do you know how can i add a busy indicator when the silent update is happening?

Comment: You cannot. The idea of silent update is that the end-user will not need to do anything. To clarify, the "white screen" is new after installing the fix packs or was it always there? you may see a white screen after a direct update because the application will re-load the web resources, at which time you may see white. Can you confirm?

Comment: no the white screen was not always there. Also with the direct update option enabled (i will edit my question too) during the first launch of the app when the user hit update the download progress doesn't show and the user doesnt get the update. he gets the update after he kills the app and reopens it from the icon

Comment: You need to update the Studio build and try again. All of those things are controlled by client-side code.

Comment: @IdanAdar both wl server and studio versions are 6.1.0.01-20140922-2007. we have deploy a new helloworklight application and the problem remains on android. the device that we use is Nexus 5 Android 4.4.4 but it occurs and on other android devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds right now like a client-side issue, as the progress bar dialog is controlled by client-side code in the JavaScript framework.

My suggestion for you is to match the used Studio version with your Server version. Re-build your application and deploy it to the device. Then, trigger a Direct Update and confirm whether the white screen / update failure was resolved.

You can download the latest available iFixes for Worklight 6.1 [from IBM Fix Central](http://www.ibm.com/support/fixcentral/).

Comment: both server and studio are in 6.1.0.02 version and the problem is now solved